# Socket stream not able to flush

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I am writing an app for android 4.2, currently debugged on a Samsung s2+.
The app establishes a connection to a server using a `Socket`, and the server is using a `ServerSocket` and the `establish()`-method to get its socket. So far so good. Since I have to make all the networking in android in a new thread, I created a new class extending `Thread` which communicates with an underlying `Activity` (for user input) using a `BlockingQueue`. The threads run method:

```
public void run() {
    Socket s = null;
    try {
        s = new Socket(info.getIp(), 1337);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String code = null;
    try {
        code = queue.take();
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e("DONE", code);

    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    out.write(code);
    out.flush();
}
```

The connection is up and running, and the logged message "DONE"+code is logged. However, nothing is received on the server side until I force close the app. Is an android thread not able to flush data?

EDIT: If  close the socket immediately after writing to it, the text arrives without having to force close the app. Why can't I read the text in the server if the socket is still alive?

Comment: Don't write code like this. Code that depends on the success of prior code in a try block should be inside that try block.

Comment: The try comment was autogenerated just to make it work, so have moved all data sending code there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add a newline to the string you sent to server , something like :

```
out.write(code+"\n");
out.flush();
```

and as EJP said above put the out.write inside the try / catch

Answer (score 0):

A socket connection only provides the ability to send and receive bytes. As soon as the client sends a byte, the server will receive it. Also, as soon as a client is disconnected, the server will know about it - this is about the extend of what you get from sockets.

The concept of a message does not exist at this level. A message is instead defined by whatever lies above the socket, so most protocols use one or more of three different ways to chunk streams of bytes into "messages"

- a special byte or sequence of bytes indicates the end of the message (a new line for example, which seems to have been your case :)
- each message starts with x bytes which provide the length of the message (so a simple "05aaaaa02bb" stream of bytes might mean that 2 messages were send - "aaaaa" and "bb"
- the entire socket connection lasts for a single message (end of message comes when the connection is closed). This is how HTTP 1.0 works for example.